# What does そうではないいわば mean in this context

Tags: grammar, translation

> 言語に対する深い関心が現代において具体的にどのような形で現れてきているかということ --- このことを考える前に、**そうではないいわば**伝統的な言語觀とはどのような性格のものであるか、ということをまず確認しておいたほうがよいと思います

From my understanding, this paragraph, ignoring the そうではないいわば means:

> Before considering the form of which the deep interest in languages emerges at present, I think that it is better to check out the character of the traditional view on languages first.

But what does そうではないいわば mean in this sentence? I am not sure what そう is referring to here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- そう refers to what was mentioned in the first part of the sentence: 現代における言語に対する関心の形 or 現代の言語観.
- そうではない is a relative clause that modifies 伝統的な言語観.
- [いわば](http://jisho.org/word/%E8%A8%80%E3%82%8F%E3%81%B0) is "what might be called ～" or "so to speak". It independently modifies the following phrase.

My attempt:

> そうではない、いわば伝統的な言語観
>   something not modern, what might be called a traditional view on languages
>   something different, a traditional view on languages, as one might say

Comment: How 'bout this?:  I believe that before thinking about what actual form the current deep interest in language is taking,  we must first confirm the character of the other, so-called ‘traditional’, view of language.

Comment: Thank you for answering.  The way you broke down the sentence made it much clearer.